# Accessing a value in nested JSON objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm using Blueimp's JQuery File Upload plugin, and so upon successful upload the callback function is:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesList})
    .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log('success'); })
    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log('error'); })
    .complete(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        console.log('complete: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(result.responseText.files[0].name);
});
```

So all I'm looking at is the `.complete` function. The first `console.log` returns:

```
complete: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"files":[{"name":"video.mp4","type":"video/mp4","size":2348842}]}","responseJSON":{"files":[{"name":"video.mp4","type":"video/mp4","size":2348842}]},"status":201,"statusText":"Created"}
```

`complete` is technically `result`, and under that is `responseText` and under that is `files`, which is an array, and `name` is a key/property in that array.

So when I try to `console.log` `result.responseText.files[0].name`, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Could someone please find what's wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result.responseText` is a string

you need to convert to an object: `JSON.parse(result.responseText)`

```
response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
console.log(response.files[0].name);
```

will work

Comment: Thank you so much! I will accept and upvote your answer in 11 minutes :)